# Visual Studio 2015 Community - Missing "Show XSL Output" option

Tags: xslt, visual-studio-2015

Per MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255828.aspx), I should be able to run an XSLT transformation by clicking the "Show XSL Output" button and/or menu option under XML.  My only two options in both an XML and XSLT file are schema-related.  Any ideas?

Comment: See [express edition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255810.aspx) section, particularly *Viewing XSLT output from the XML Editor*

Answer (score 1):

Credit should go to har07, but this feature is not available in community edition.